# Android: ViewRootCalledFromWrongThreadException upon creating an alertdialog

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create and show an `AlertDialog` when I send a request to my server, and cancel it when I receive a response. This is my code:

```
View alertdialog_2 = LayoutInflater.from(candidate_registration_1.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout2,null);

AlertDialog.Builder dialog_2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(candidate_registration_1.this);

dialog_2.setView(alertdialog_2);

MaterialTextView txt = alertdialog_2.findViewById(R.id.dialogtext);

AlertDialog wait_dialog = dialog_2.create();

wait_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

call = api.save_data(array.get(0),array.get(1));

if(call != null){

    wait_dialog.show();

    final int[] dotcount = {0};

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){ //creating a ... animation in text inside dialog
        @Override
        public void run(){
            dotcount[0] += 1;
            if(dotcount[0] != 3){
                txt.append(".");
            }
            else{
                dotcount[0] = 0;
                String tmp = txt.getText().toString();
                tmp = tmp.replace(".","");
                txt.setText(tmp);
            }
        }
    },0,1000);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
            wait_dialog.cancel();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {}
    });
}
```

When I execute the code, I get this error:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

in the line `txt.append(".");`. Why is that? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `TimerTask` is being executed on the `Timer` thread, not the thread that created the `TimerTask`, `Timer`, or `MaterialTextView`.

From https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer :

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially.